# Exoplayer change current video seamlessly

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to change current playing video to another seamlessly. But there is a little bit delay before the next video will be playing. I don't know what the next video will be. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use playlists with ExoPlayer. This way the playback transitions at the end of item 1 to 2 without buffering.

```
DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource mainSource = new DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource();
mainSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource1);
player.prepare(mainSource);

// later...
mainSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource2);
```

As soon as you know the second media you can add it while the player is playing.

https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/dynamic-playlists-with-exoplayer-6f53e54a56c0